# Mezclar dos Arrays

Tags: java, array

tengo un programa en el que se pide al usuario la longitud y los datos de dos arrays para luego mostrarlos en un tercero asi: a1, b1, a2, b2, ...
Tengo casi todo el codigo, pero a la hora de declarar el tamaño del array c (la mezcla de ambos) quería que sumase la longitud del array a y la del array b, este es mi codigo:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ejer5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int long1, long2, long3 = 0;

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("PROGRAMA QUE PIDA LA LONGITUD Y DATOS DE"
                + "\n DOS ARRAYS Y LOS MUESTRE EN UNO SOLO");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");

        System.out.print("Introduce la longitud del 1º Array: ");
        long1 = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduce la longitud del 2º Array: ");
        long2 = teclado.nextInt();

        if (long1 > long2) {
            long3 = long1;
        } else {
            long3 = long2;
        }

        int[] a = new int[long1];
        int[] b = new int[long2];
        int[] c = new int[long3];

        System.out.println("\nIntroduzca el arreglo a: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Introduzca el digito %d: ", i + 1);
            a[i] = teclado.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("\nIntroduzca el arreglo b:");
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Introduzca el digito %d: ", i + 1);
            b[i] = teclado.nextInt();
        }
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (long3 - 1); i++) {
            c[j] = a[i];
            j++;
            c[j] = b[i];
            j++;

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < long3; i++) {
            System.out.println(c[i] + " ");

        }
    }
}
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme con ello, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

La longitud del array c es la suma de `long1` + `long2`

```
 int[] c = new int[long1 + long2];
```

También se puede usar la propiedad `length` del array:

```
int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sé hacerlo con una longitud en los arrays predefinida de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ejer6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("PROGRAMA QUE PIDA LOS DATOS DE"
                + "\n DOS ARRAYS Y LOS MUESTRE EN UNO SOLO");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");

        int[] a = new int[5];
        int[] b = new int[5];
        int[] c = new int[10];

        System.out.println("\nIntroduzca el arreglo a: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Introduzca el digito %d: ", i + 1);
            a[i] = teclado.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("\nIntroduzca el arreglo b:");
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Introduzca el digito %d: ", i + 1);
            b[i] = teclado.nextInt();
        }
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            c[j] = a[i];
            j++;
            c[j] = b[i];
            j++;

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(c[i] + " ");

        }
    }
}
```

Pero si quiero que el usuario introduzca la longitud de los arrays ya se me complica la cosa. Estoy seguro que el cambio no puede ser mucho, pero aún así me está costando sacarlo.